# How does one do a $text search on MongoDB with motor?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, tornado-motor

I have created an index for the db.

```
res = yield dbEmail["emails"].create_index([("subject", pymongo.TEXT)])
```

Now I'm trying to search on the created index by

```
dbEmail["emails"].find({$text: {$search: "dogs"}}, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score: {$meta: "textScore"}})
```

which I found doesn't work. The motor docs say the filter argument in db.collection.find(filter) is a SON object. When I try list_indexes() on my collection, they are SON objects too. But then

```
for index in (yield dbEmail["emails"].list_indexes()):
    searchResults = yield dbEmail["emails"].find(index)
```

also results in error. How do we $text search on index with motor?

edit: replying to Niel

My initial db collection looks like this:

```
emails = {"_id" : ObjectId("xxcxcdsfas"),"subject": "Joe owns a dog", "content": "Dogs are man's best friend", "likes": 60, "year": 2015,"language": "english"},
         {"_id" : ObjectId("xxcxcdsfas"),"subject": "Dogs eat cats and dog eats pigeons too", "content": "Cats are not evil", "likes": 30, "year": 2015,"language": "english"},
         {"_id" : ObjectId("xxcxcdsfas"),"subject": "Cats eat rats", "content": "Rats do not cook food", "likes": 55, "year": 2014, "language": "english"},
         {"_id" : ObjectId("xxcxcdsfas"), "subject": "Rats eat Joe", "content": "Joe ate a rat", "likes": 75, "year": 2014, "language": "english"}
```

After creating the index (which is being created, I've verified), the final results that I require should be something like,

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxcxcdsfas"), "subject" : "Dogs eat cats and dog eats pigeons too", "content" : "Cats are not evil", "likes" : 30, "year" : 2015, "language" : "english", "score" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxcxcdsfas"), "subject" : "Joe owns a dog", "content" : "Dogs are man's best friend", "likes" : 60, "year" : 2015, "language" : "english", "score" : 0.6666666666666666 }
```

The first one has a higher score because dog appears twice in the subject, as opposed to once in the second one.

I checked that the index is valid with the following code:

```
    for item in (yield dbEmail["emails"].index_information()).items():
        print(item)
```

The response or index is below:

```
('_id_', {'v': 2, 'key': [('_id', 1)], 'ns': 'emailInfo.emails'})
('subject_text', {'v': 2, 'key': [('_fts', 'text'), ('_ftsx', 1)], 'ns': 'emailInfo.emails', 'weights': SON([('subject', 1)]), 'default_language': 'english', 'language_override': 'language', 'textIndexVersion': 3})
```

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than "does not work". Show some data with something expected to match. Show that the expected created index is present and valid.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks, edited the question.

Comment: So what do you actually get as a response? You still have not explained the problem. What is it?

Comment: @NeilLunn it says "tornado.gen.BadYieldError: yielded unknown object MotorCursor(<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x103b93da0>)", i'm sure i'm making a syntax error, but I coudn't find the right one in the motor documentation or otherwise

Comment: @NeilLunn i need to search the db for the $text for which i'm trying the above approach,

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved, the command "db.collection.command()" made it work,

```
searchResults = yield dbEmail.command({"find": "emails",
                                      "filter": {"$text": { "$search": "dogs"}}})
```

Comment: No that is not the solution. The correct solution would have been easy to find by simply looking for the `BadYieldError` you eventually stated in comments as the essential part of your question instead. You cannot `yield` on something that is not actually an async action yet.